# Expo throws : Permission denied when starting expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, arch

I have had a code of react native. I installed the npm pacakges and when I run `npm start` it says permission denied. I tried to change ownership using `sudo chown linux: node_modules/.bin/**`. But it also didn't work. I tried to start being root that also didn't work.
**The error is like this.**

```
linux@linux ~/quiz $ npm start

> quiz@1.0.0 start
> expo start

sh: line 1: /home/linux/quiz/node_modules/.bin/expo: Permission denied
```

My OS: **Endeavour OS (Arch based)**

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Try using sudo. So "sudo npm start"

Comment: I tried it didn't work. Here: https://i.ibb.co/8xMDYVL/2023-05-19-06-04.png

Comment: `npm run start`

Answer (score 1):

Few things to try out.

Check the permissions of the node_modules directory and its contents to ensure that the user running the command has the necessary permissions. Navigate to the project directory and run the following command to set the correct ownership and permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) node_modules/
```

Sometimes, issues can arise from a corrupted npm cache. Clear the cache by running the following command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Remove the node_modules directory and reinstall the npm packages by executing the following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Instead of running npm start, you can try using npx to start your React Native project. Execute the following command:

```
npx expo start
```

Ensure that you are using the latest versions of npm and Node.js. Update them to their latest stable versions by running the following commands:

```
npm install -g npm
nvm install stable (if you use Node Version Manager - NVM)
```

If all else fails, you can try running the command with elevated privileges using sudo. However, it's generally recommended to avoid using sudo with npm commands. If you choose to proceed with sudo, use the following command:

```
sudo npm start
```

Comment: 1. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) node_modules/`  --argument exceeds 2M, 2. `npm cache clean --force` -- same error, 3. ```rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
``` --- Same error, 4. `npx expo start` -- ```npx start
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/linux/.npm/_logs/2023-05-19T00_29_55_780Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I had got that project from a friend who was running widows. I think that was the problem. When I fresh start the project form scratch in my system it worked.

Comment: Alright, perfect! Glad it's working for you now.